# How to install netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I'm trying to install Netbeans on Ubuntu. I downloaded `netbeans-7.3-javaee-linux.sh`, but when I opened it it didn't work. I tried opening it from a terminal, but it didn't help, and I ran:

```
# sudo chmod +x /home/amal/netbeans-7.3-javaee-linux.sh
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the script as follows:

```
$ sudo bash /home/amal/netbeans-7.3-javaee-linux.sh
```

This script will execute and install netbeans.